# GLSL/OpenGL shading language errors, Invalid storage qualifiers

Tags: java, opengl, glsl

I got an error when compiling my shader in GLSL shading language that is

```
ERROR: 0:4: Invalid storage qualifiers 'attribute' in global 
variablecontext
ERROR: 0:7: Use of undeclared identifier 'gl_Position'
ERROR: 0:7: Use of undeclared identifier 'position'
ERROR: 0:8: Use of undeclared identifier 'position'
ERROR: 0:8: Use of undeclared identifier 'position'
```

Could not compile shader!

My code:

```
#version 120

varying vec3 colour;
attribute vec3 position;

void main(void){
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
    colour = vec3(position.x + 0.5, 1.0, position.y + 0.5);
}
```

btw this is a vertex shader.

Edit: This is how it loads the shader

```
protected void bindAtrribute(int attribute){
    GL20.glBindAttribLocation(programID, attribute, "position");
}

private static int loadShader(String file, int type){
    StringBuilder shaderSource = new StringBuilder();
    try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        while((line = reader.readLine())!=null){
            shaderSource.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        reader.close();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    int shaderID = GL20.glCreateShader(type);
    GL20.glShaderSource(shaderID, shaderSource);
    GL20.glCompileShader(shaderID);
    if(GL20.glGetShaderi(shaderID, GL20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS )== GL11.GL_FALSE){
        System.out.println(GL20.glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderID, 500));
        System.err.println("Could not compile shader!");
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    return shaderID;
}
```

This isn't the whole class

Comment: The shader looks fine (and compiles for me without errors). I had to removed the last ` character, if this does not come from SO formatting, then this might be a problem. Can you show how you load the shader? Are you sure the `#version` line is passed to the OpenGL?

Comment: i edited. with the loader

Comment: What is the actual `type` parameter passed to load `loadShader`? Is it `GL_VERTEX_SHADER` or is it something else?

Comment: Yep, GL20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER Rabbid76

Comment: Which OpenGL context version you use?

Comment: I haven't specified a version, so I guess the default.